# Asterisk in interactive specification

Tags: commands, interactive, read-only-mode

Just when is it appropriate to put the asterisk `*` into the interactive spec of a command function? The elisp manual says the effect is to cause an error if the command is attempted in a read only buffer, so clearly this should be done when, in some sense, the command modifies the current buffer.

But this is not precise enough; is the mere *possibility* of a modification sufficient grounds? What about a command like `untabify` which *could* potentially modify my buffer but in fact it never does because I never use physical tab characters?

On the other hand, pretty much any command can be made a no-op by a zero prefix argument, so I guess if I wanted to be sure a modification would in fact occur I'd never use the asterisk.

I just wish the manual were more explicit about this. What is your interpretation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is untrue, assuming I understand what you mean:

> *On the other hand, pretty much any command can be made a no-op by a zero prefix argument*

Beyond that, the answer, IMO, is that you do what you like when defining commands. The point of the `*` and its doc is to let you know *what it does*.  How/when you *decide to use it* is up to you.

It's you who answers the question, ***"Do I want invocation of this command to raise an error if the buffer is read-only?"*** That's all - there's nothing more to it.

Some particular command, or some particular command author, might well want the error to be raised only if the command *would be sure to modify* the buffer. But that's not what `*` does. I raises an error systematically, anytime the command is invoked in a read-only buffer.

---

You can see for yourself what `*` would do for `untabify` in a read-only buffer with no `TAB` chars:

```lisp
(defun my-untabify ()
  (interactive "*")
  (untabify (region-beginning) (region-end)))
```

---

You ask, in a comment, whether there is some convention regarding the use of `*` in `interactive`. My answer is no, not as far as I know. I don't believe there's anything in [Coding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html), for example.

And I've tried to give a reason why: The behavior of `*` is just to raise an error whenever the command is invoked interactively in a read-only buffer. What convention could there possibly be about that? If you use `*` then it'll do just that.

Whether you *want* it to raise an error in such a context depends on you and what you expect your users will expect in the particular context. How could there be any general guideline about that? That's a judgment call based on the *context*; it can't be something context-independent.

I suppose you could imagine trying to categorize situations that combine a read-only buffer with various kinds of commands, and come up with some general rules for which kinds of commands in which read-only contexts might be better candidates for raising such an error.

I don't expect that exercise would be worthwhile, but I could be wrong. In any case, I don't think such a classification has been done - I know of no such guideline.

Comment: Thanks for answering. There are places in elisp where a pleasant user experience depends on the programmer following a convention. Keybindings, which of them are "reserved for the user", are one such - and sure enough, quite often I try to use some package, even a popular one, only to see it mess up my keybindings. I do not want my code to be like that. So I was interested if there was a coding convention associated with this particular mechanism. Your answer sounds like "No", am I reading you right?

Comment: Yes, you're reading me right. But perhaps someone else will point to some such convention... The Elisp manual has these entries for `convention`, among others, which you might want to study: `buffer display conventions`,  `coding conventions in Emacs Lisp`, `major mode conventions`, `minor mode conventions`, `programming conventions`.